# Proving that $M(r) := \max_{|z| = r}|f(z)|$ is continuous using the sequence criterion

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f: B_1(0) \to \mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic in $B_1(0)$ and for $0
>  \leq r < 1$ define $$M(r) := \max_{|z| = r}|f(z)|$$ Show that $M:
>  [0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

I would like to apply the sequence criterion unlike the approach made [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88937/fb-10-rightarrow-holomorphic-max-z-r-f-monotonically-and-conti).  Let $r \in [0,1)$ and $(r_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $[0,1)$ such that $r_n \to r$. The idea is to use the continuity of $f$ as follows:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} M(r_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \max_{|z| = r_n}|f(z)| = \lim_{n \to \infty}|f(z_n)| = |f(z)|$$ where $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is so that $M(r_n) = |f(z_n)|$ and $M(r) = |f(z)|$. How would I prove that $z_n \to z$ or for a subsequence $z_{n_j} \to z$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I already told you to find a bound for $|M(r)-M(r+h)|$ (this is how we prove a function is continuous in general..)

Comment: Saying it exists a sequence $z_n \to z$ such that $|f(z_n)| = M(|z_n|)$ and $|f(z)| = M(|z|)$ is the same as saying $M$ is continuous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work on a real analysis book, where all such things are detailed.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $|z| \le R$, then $g(z) = |f(z)|$ is uniformly continuous so there exists $G \ge 0$ continuous, $G(0) = 0$ such that $|g(x)-g(y)| \le G(|x-y|)$ for all $|x| \le R,|y| \le R$.

This means that for every $t$ :  $|g(e^{it}(r+h))-g(e^{it}r)| \le G(h)$.

- If  $M(r+h) > M(r)$, take $t$ such that $M(r+h) = g(e^{it}(r+h))$. Then 
  $|M(r+h)-g(e^{it}r)| \le G(h)$. But $|M(r+h)-g(e^{it}r)| = M(r+h) - g(e^{it}r) \ge M(r+h) - M(r) $ $=|M(r+h) - M(r)|$ and $|M(r+h) - M(r)| \le G(h)$
- If  $M(r+h) \le M(r)$, take $t$ such that $M(r) = g(e^{it}r)$. Then 
  $|M(r)-g(e^{it}(r+h))| \le G(h)$. But $|M(r)-g(e^{it}(r+h))| = M(r)-g(e^{it}(r+h)) \ge M(r)-M(r+h)$ $ = |M(r)-M(r+h)|$ so that $|M(r)-M(r+h) | \le G(h)$.

Qed. $|M(r+h) - M(r)| \le G(h)$ which means $M$ is uniformly continuous on $|z| \le R$.

Comment: Thank you alot. Yes, I have to repeat thos things. One last question: Why exactly does from the uniform continuity on $|z| \leq R < 1$ the uniform continuity on $0\leq |z| < 1$ follow?

Comment: @TheGeekGreek : The continuity on $|z| < 1$ implies the uniform continuity on $|z| \le R$ for any $R < 1$. This is again an important theorem in real analysis, see for example there https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445735/compactly-supported-continuous-function-is-uniformly-continuous